# Cannot access image uploaded at Laravel public storage

Tags: laravel, file-upload, storage

My project is in a subfolder `/example-domain.com/public_html/v1/` where the folder `v1` is the root of my Laravel project. I followed this tutorial from https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk and created a symbolic link from v1 folder. Then I do some uploading and manage to get the file uploaded in this path `/storage/app/public/cars/`.

Here is my code

```
$file     = $request->file('image');
$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

Storage::disk('public')->putFile('cars', $file);
$contents = URL::asset('storage/cars/'.$fileName);

echo $contents;
```

The echo return the url `https://www.example-domain.com/storage/cars/honda-jazz-1-5-vx-i-dtec-sunset-orange-car-500x500.jpg` but when I paste the url in the browser, it returned 403 Forbidden no permission to access.

**Note:** I do only the `php artisan storage:link` part from the documentation I referred to.

**Edit:**
I have rewrote the `.htaccess` file from the domain main root to point to `v1` so the url will read all content from `v1` by default.

Comment: Check the permission of the folder and also i note the url should also include the 'v1' string!

Comment: @SachinKumar the folder `/storage/app/public/cars` permission is `0755` and I don't think I have to include `v1` because I have re-write the url redirection from `.htaccess` where the main domain is pointing to the content in `v1` when accessing it from URL.

Comment: Alright then I think you should mention redirection thing in your questions. Anyway, did you try access the image url without using the symbolic link on browser?

Comment: And i hope in your htaccess, you make the redirection rule for any kind of resources include images as well!

Comment: Yes I can access it without using the symbolic link. My htaccess is like this `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`

Comment: Did you use shared hosting? And did you check by file explorer that the symbolic link exist or not. If not exist then create manually.

Comment: Yes it's a shared hosting. The link is exist. I have checked and should be working as I am able to upload to that directory.

Comment: In case you're on a shared hosting, you must create symlink by your self instead of using php artisan storage:link. The reason is the way that php artisan create that link, it uses absolute path and that's what causes 403 forbidden. so remove the symbolic link first that generated by php artisan command and run thia command "ln -sr dev/storage/app/public/ dev/public/storage". Obviously change command path accordingly

Comment: So I will run this command at the root folder of my project which is inside `v1` right?

Comment: right. or simply search how to make a symbolic link(which is a shortcut in windows) on your current os.